# Build failed for ios on codemagic

Tags: codemagic

Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           62.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): ../programs/flutter_3_7_5/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.0/lib/src/material_with_modal_page_route.dart:4:1: Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.

Encountered error while building for device.

Build failed :|
Failed to build for iOS

Answer (score 0):

As the error mentions:

```dart
'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
```

Can you make sure that you are only importing one of the packages?

For further queries, you can ask in GitHub discussions:
https://github.com/orgs/codemagic-ci-cd/discussions.